# shell script program for count num of line

Tags: linux, shell, codeigniter

Write a shell script to count the number of lines, characters, words in a file (without the use of commands). Also delete the occurrence of word “Linux” from the file wherever it appears and save the results in a new file.

Comment: http://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

This is the nearest I could get without using any third party packages...

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
while read -r line
do
    count=$((count + 1))
done < "$filename"
echo "Number of lines: $count"
```

Answer (score 0):

- Sachin Bharadwaj gave a script that counts the lines.
- Now, to count the words, we can use `set` to split the line into `$#` positional parameters.
- And to count the characters, we can use the parameter length: `${#line}`.
- Finally, to delete every “Linux”, we can use pattern substitution: `${line//Linux}`.

(Cf. [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).)

All taken together:

```
while read -r line
do
    ((++count))
    set -- $line
    ((wordcount+=$#))
    ((charcount+=${#line}+1))   # +1 for the '\n'
    echo "${line//Linux}"
done < "$filename" >anewfile
echo "Number of lines: $count"
echo "Number of words: $wordcount"
echo "Number of chars: $charcount"
```